# Python Ansible Evaluating Output of Task

Tags: python, ansible, task

I'm a new user of Ansible and am trying to see how I can perform an automation task using Ansible. I would like to connect to several servers and cat a file to get a list of items (list_2). I then want to check if that list of items is in another list (list_1).  I would like then print a table showing which items from list_2 are in list_1? Is there a way to accomplish this via Ansible without pushing a script?

The below gathers both lists and puts them into a register but I am unsure how to evaluate to see if the items in list_2 are contained in list_1.

```
list_1 = 'red, green, yellow, blue, orange, purple'
list_2 = 'green, blue, purple'

hosts: myhost

tasks:
- name: get list 1
  shell: "cat /dir/list_1"
  register: list_1

tasks:
- name: get list 2
  shell: "cat /dir/list_2"
  register: list_2
```

Desired Output:

```
list_1  list2inlist1
red     No
green   Yes
blue    Yes
orange  No
purple  Yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that will get close to your desired output

```
- name: print intersection
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ list_1.stdout.split(', ') }}"
  when: item in list_2.stdout.split(', ')
```

If you really want the same syntax as your desired output I think a template would be the easiest way.

in your tasks:

```
- name: print intersection template
  template:
    src: intersection.j2
    dest: /some_dir/intersection.txt
```

in intersection.j2:

```
list1   list2inlist1
{% for item in list_1.stdout.split(', ') %}
{% if item in list_2.stdout.split(', ') %}
{{ item }}    YES
{% else %}
{{ item }}    NO
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```